# JQuery on change hitting default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to dynamically load content with select.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lang").on("change", function () {
        switch(this.value) {
            case "pl":
                $("#content").load("pl.html");
            case "en":
                $("#content").load("en.html");
            default:
                alert("default")
        }
    });
});
```

```
<select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option value="en">en</option>
    <option value="pl">pl</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Whenever I am changing value the default alert is occurring and the content is not always updated properly.

Comment: You neglected to put `break;` statements at the end of your cases.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#syntax: _"`case valueN`:  [...] If the expression matches the specified valueN (which can be any expression), execution starts **from the first statement after that case clause until either the end of the switch statement or the first encountered break.**"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If break is omitted, execution will proceed to the next case clause, even to the default clause, regardless of whether the value of that clause matches.

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#breaking_and_fall-through)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lang").on("change", function() {
    switch (this.value) {
      case "pl":
        $("#content").load("pl.html");
        break;
      case "en":
        $("#content").load("en.html");
        break;
      default:
        alert("default")
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="lang" id="lang">
  <option value="en">en</option>
  <option value="pl">pl</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>
```